# Is there a way for printing directly to POS printer on MONO?

Tags: c#, mono

Is there some way of sending raw text to POS printer on Mono?

For now, printing is done with printdocument.
That works for lpt and usb printers. 
Serial printer does not work, probably because of its driver.

Finding drivers for linux is another problem.

So, does anyone have some advice how to solve this printing problem some other way?